# How to make a TTF or OTF from SVG or BMP

Tags: python, svg, fonts, bitmap, truetype

I am working on a pixel font which I am able to create with `Pillow`. `Pillow` can export `*.bmp` files. I would like to get from `*.bmp` to `*.ttf` or `*.otf`. In my current example I have a letter `a` (unicode `0061`) and letter `p` (unicode `0070`). I will eventually represent the full alphabet, but I use just these two letters for illustration.

**How can I make a valid `ttf` or `otf` from my individual `*.bmp` letters?**

I currently make `*.bmp` then convert to `*.svg` because I have read most font programs like "Glyphs Mini 2" and "Font Forge" can import `*.svg`. The problem is that I do not know how to combine my individual `*.svg` into a valid TTF or OTF font file.

### Try 1

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from potrace import Bitmap
import numpy as np
import os

# p
p = np.array(
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
)

# a
a = np.array(
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
)

dir_bmp = "bmp/"
dir_svg = "svg/"


def array_to_drawing(letter_name: str, array: np.array):
    """Converts a numpy array to a drawing.

    Args:
        letter_name (str): The name of the letter to save the image as.
        array (np.array): The 2D numpy array to convert.
    """
    # Create an image with a white background
    width = 320
    height = 1024
    img = Image.new("1", (width, height), color="white")

    # Create a draw object to draw on the image
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Draw the letter which the 2d numpy array represents
    for row in range(array.shape[0]):
        for col in range(array.shape[1]):
            if array[row, col] == 1:
                x0 = col * 64
                y0 = row * 64
                draw.rectangle([x0, y0, x0 + 64, y0 - 64], fill="black")

    img.save(dir_bmp + letter_name + ".bmp")
    print(
        "potrace "
        + dir_bmp
        + letter_name
        + ".bmp --svg -o "
        + dir_svg
        + letter_name
        + ".svg"
    )
    os.system(
        "potrace "
        + dir_bmp
        + letter_name
        + ".bmp --svg -o "
        + dir_svg
        + letter_name
        + ".svg"
    )


array_to_drawing("p", p)
array_to_drawing("a", a)
```

## Letter p

[image: letter p]

## Letter a

[image: letter a]

Comment: FontForge should be able to import .bmp (or at least .png) files. You first [import them as background images for glyphs](https://fontforge.org/docs/ui/menus/filemenu.html#filemenu-bitmapfiles) and subsequently, in the [Bitmap View](https://fontforge.org/docs/ui/mainviews/bitmapview.html), import that bitmap image into the glyph proper.

Comment: Thanks. I will get myself oriented with the GUI. I was more interested in how to add that functionality in the script itself.